# How to achieve this join in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm working on an application that has the following associations:

```
class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chart_group
  has_many :charts, :through => :chart_groups
end

class ChartGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charts
  belongs_to :report
end

class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chart_group
end
```

One part of the application requires that we display the top 20 reports, and for each report we display the first chart (as kind of a snapshot). They way i've been doing this is, in the controller just selecting the reports;

```
@reports = Report.limit(20)
```

and then in the views just doing;

```
@reports.each do |report|
   <%= report.charts.first.title %>
end
```

Which seems fine and runs fast, but falls foul of the "N + 1 queries problem" - i would be getting one database round trip per report, so 21 hits. So I have a couple of questions

1) How can I change my original query to get the first chart? I tried using ".joins" but the problem with that is that there can be LOADS of charts associated with any one report, and there can be hundreds of reports. I can't work out how to include the "only the first chart" part into the statement.

2) Actually doing it the way I am, I have noticed that the logs are all saying "CACHE LOAD" - is rails doing some magic here for me? Am I worrying about nothing?

Answer (score 2):

Rail's [Eager Loading](http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading) should help here.

The following should load all charts associated with requested reports:

```
@reports = Report.limit(20).includes(:charts)
```

AR will load all requested report `limit(20)` and find all charts associated with these reports and also load these into memory.

To load only the first chart into memory for each report requires additional work:

- add an additional column to `reports.first_chart_id`
- define an additional association from `Report` to `Chart` in relation to `first_chart_id`

Report should be modified as follows:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_chart, :foreign_key => 'first_chart_id', :class_name => 'Chart'
end
```

Then:

```
@reports = Report.limit(20).includes(:first_chart)
```

The only caveat with the above is that first_chart_id will have to be set during `Report` instance create/update.

Another solution is to perform two DB queries:

Fetch all reports then iterate through fetched reports, extract @report.id then query charts to return the first chart only (no idea how the first chart is defined)

```
@reports = Report.limit(20)
@report_ids = @reports.collect{|r| r.id}
@first_charts = Chart.find_by_report_ids(@report_ids)


class Chart
  def self.find_by_report_ids(report_ids)
    {}.tap do |result|
      #not sure what your scheme is like for Report and Chart... so guessing  
      where(:id => report_ids).group(:report_id).each do |chart|
        result[chart.report_id] = chart
      end
    end
  end
end
```

find_by_report_ids returns a hash of charts indexed by `report.id`, which gives you quick access to a report's first chart in your view

```
@reports.each do |report|
   <%= @first_charts[report.id].title %>
end
```

Unfortunately sometimes you have to write additional code for many-to-many type relationships but these can be mostly solved by using two DB trips, which is still much better than O(N) queries.

HTH

Comment: Hi, This is what I was talking about - if I do that it's going to try to load every chart associated with the report into memory, but I only need the first one. When I try doing it this way the code becomes really inefficient and I get a massive performance hit.